# Snapchat Like Filters for React Native

Tags: react-native, snapchat, react-native-vision-camera

I'm working on a React Native app and exploring options to implement face AR filters similar to Snapchat. Currently, I am using React Native Vision Camera, but I am uncertain about its suitability. I am looking for objective information on available free Face AR Filters SDKs for React Native.

Can anyone provide insights into different Face AR Filters SDKs available for React Native? I need a solution that is easy to integrate, offers a variety of filters, and supports video recording capabilities. Any factual information or experiences shared would be highly valuable. Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [react-native-**deepAR**](https://developer.deepar.ai/demo-projects/e7be8c6c-8fff-4e20-bbe3-56c3071b7ab9)

**OR**

You can use [React Native **Skia** - Image Filter](https://shopify.github.io/react-native-skia/docs/image-filters/overview/)

For using `react native skia` you need to have [react-native-**vision-camera**](https://React%20Native%20Skia%20React%20Native%20Skia) for controlling camera.

`Read`  [Apply filter to photos - github discussion](https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-vision-camera/issues/724) to understand better.

Comment: Thanks, and do you have any idea about detecting user(s) face(s) using react-native-vision-camera's frame processer? I can't find any tutorials on how to do it. I'm new to app development, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can mark answer as Approved, to help other facing the same issue. 
With a quick search, i found two ways you can `achieve` it [Vision-Camera sourse](https://github.com/rodgomesc/vision-camera-face-detector)  & [youtube source](https://youtu.be/cbIhP82gd2s?si=LF_OAAqXlM2XTV_C). Yes i would be glad to help you, can find me with the same username everywhere.

Comment: Marked the answer as SOLVED and Thanks for helping (: .

Comment: hey, so i tried both of them and both of them are causing me problems 
1. DeepAR: 
Execution failed for task ':tasks'.
> Could not create task ':react-native-deepar:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
   > In order to compile Java 9+ source, please set compileSdkVersion to 30 or above

my compileSdkVersion is set to 33 and i couldn't find any issue about this.

2. React Native Skia:
The problem is not particularly with RN Skia but Frame Processer to detect the face in the first place I cant tell the full problem here because of the characters limit!

Comment: to handle these issue, you should read there `docs` and  `issues on github`, you will find solution. if you still have issue make a new `stackOverFlow` question.

Comment: ok I'll make a new question